# Which database to use with Django and Python 3?

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql, mariadb

I'm writing my first application with Django and Python 3.3.3. I've always used MySQL for others projects, but it seems to have some problems with Python 3.X and MySQL :

> At the time of writing, the latest release of MySQLdb (1.2.4) doesn’t support Python 3. In order to use MySQLdb under Python 3, you’ll have to install an unofficial fork, such as MySQL-for-Python-3.
>
> This port is still in alpha. In particular, it doesn’t support binary data, making it impossible to use django.db.models.BinaryField. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/).

It seems to be the same thing with MariaDB.

So, what, you - django developpers - use for your database ? MySQL with MySQL-for-Python-3 or PostgreSQL ? (I will have some joins and tables with billions rows.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most Django developers that I know of uses PostgreSQL, I don't see any reason not to use it. You will never miss anything from mysql. For reference, read this blog from Disqus, http://justcramer.com/2010/05/30/scaling-threaded-comments-on-django-at-disqus/ they have billion of rows.

Comment: Postgresql plays much nicer with migrations (using South) than MySQL.